# Uploading/Downloading PHP script issue with the Current Dedicated Server

Tags: php, web-hosting

I think this problem is related to this ServerFault because it has something to do with Dedicated servers configurations.

**I have this php script that Download files from MediaFire website and upload it directly to my dedicated server, then it generates you the link of the file after that.
The thing is the script works fine on my previous vps, but now with the new dedicated server, while the script is upload the file it hangs(white page) and does not show the link of the new file (which it is on my new dedicated server) but it actually uploaded because when I check the file via ftp, it has been fully uploaded.
I think this issue has to be with php and server configuration which I'm not very fimiler with.**

So, I will appreciate any answer and help from you guys. I would love to put the script link to test out, but I think it's risky, so you can PM me to send it to you.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATED:

> Here is the errors logs for the script: this is the error logs, [Fri
>   Nov 04 00:03:43 2011] [error] [client 84.235.73.168] (70007)The
>   timeout specified has expired: ap_content_length_filter:
>   apr_bucket_read() failed, referer: xxxx.com/xxxxx/index.php

Comment: Check your PHP error log. Without more information on the script or errors produced we cannot help. There is no PM feature on this site.

Comment: I will check it today and will get back to you as soon as possible

Comment: please check my post, I've added the error logs. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities to not get things right. To say some:

1- Missing a required package.

2- Incorreect permissions.

3- Server misconfiguration.

The best thing to do is to check the server logs and you may need to set 'display_errors' to on in php.ini file.

Comment: Hi, this is the error logs,   [Fri Nov 04 00:03:43 2011] [error] [client 84.235.73.168] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed, referer: http://xxxx.com/xxxxx/index.php